# JSON to java.sql.timestamp deserialization loses hours, causes date to lose a day

Tags: java, angularjs, json, timestamp

I've got a Spring app that has entities storing dates as `java.sql.Timestamp`.  The angular front end is capturing the changes in `yyyy-mm-dd` format but when the JSON gets deserialized to the timestamp it loses several hours and the net result is the dd portion loses a day.

I understand this has something to do with the timezone, but can't figure out the quickest solution.  Is there an annotation that can fix this?

Here's my code:

Entity class variable

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Timestamp dateNeeded;
```

JSON data incoming:

```
"DateNeeded": "2017-12-25"
```

I'd prefer to NOT have to change from `java.sql.Timestamp`, but have seen guidance to this affect... something about Jackson not playing nice with the java.sql package.  This would be my last option and would prefer a change that allows me to keep Timestamp.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you've ignored the timezone.  If you're an actual "Hoosier" you're likely to be 5 hours behind UTC (though I believe Indiana is a place with random timezones).  Is it about that amount of time?

Comment: The `Timestamp` class is old and long outmoded. What do you want to cling to that for?

Comment: Ole, if not Timestamp, what would you suggest?  The DB is MySQL storing data as DateTime.

Comment: I believe the best solution is to change the datatype in MySQL to [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and then use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in Java. Then there are no hours to deal with or lose. If you cannot change the column type, you should probably use `LocalDateTime` in Java.

Comment: A tip, @HoosierDude, put an at sign in front of my name, and Stack Overflow will signal to me that there is a comment for me, which greatly improves the chance that I see it.

Comment: @OleV.V. - thanks for the tip on the mention and the suggestion for the types.  I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to timezone. When you don't specify a time, it sets it to 00:00:000

Then its converted to milliseconds and a Timestamp object is constructed. And since the local timezone has an offset of UTC some hours are subtracted.

You would have to replace dateNeeded with an incremented Timestamp, one that is offset by the local timezone offset before storing it.